# Using context for timeouts in a channel based pipeline

Tags: go

I have a design that makes use of a pipeline of channels between workers. The basic design is that tasks placed on fan-out channels to long liked gorouteans that act as workers, consuming the jobs from the channel and working on them.

```
+-------------+                        +--------+
| task source |  == fan out channels =>| worker |
+-------------+                        +--------+
```

Each worker goroutean lives for the lifetime of the process and will process multiple jobs.

However due to new requirements I now have to implement a timeout for completion of processing the task through the system. My understanding is that timeouts for things that span across functions are normally achieved via contexts.

However I'm unsure how to propagate context between workers that are connected via channels.

Alternatively am I asking the wrong question and their is another solution better suited for my requirements?

Comment: Pass the same context to all the goroutines when you create them.

Comment: That depends is the timeout based on job basis or is a timeout for workers? Can you maybe add a flow diagram to make it more clear

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava I've made changes that hopefully clarify this.  The timeout is on a job basis.

Comment: Pass the context as part of the job (ie the message you're sending over the channel to the workers).

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to pass into goroutine channel and context, like this:

```
// ctx created earlier for all goroutines

for i := 0; i < workersCount; i++ {
    go worker(ctx, jobsChan)
}
```

so now you can timeout all workers.

**But** probably your timeout related to 1 particular job in 1 worker that has nothing to do with other workers and jobs, so you need to create context for each job handling, like this:

```
for i := 0; i < workersCount; i++ {
    go worker(jobsChan)
}

func worker(jobs <-chan Job) {
   // read from chan
   // and create ctx for job
   ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 500*time.Millisecond)
   // ...
}
```

or (if I got @Adrian point right) you can do something like this:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 500*time.Millisecond)
job.ctx = ctx
job.ctxCancel = cancel
// put job int chan

for i := 0; i < workersCount; i++ {
    go worker(jobsChan)
}

func worker(jobs <-chan Job) {
   // read from chan
   // deal with job.ctx
   // ...
}
```

Comment: This only works if all jobs have the same timeout, *and* the timeout is from when the job is picked up, not when it was submitted (which would be pretty unusual).

Comment: @Adrian regarding when it was submitted - just add into job info like submited_at with unix timestamp and in worker when job is picked up just do math and calculate actual time difference...

Comment: Which means you may be creating a context that already expired, and puts that responsibility on the worker; it seems cleaner to just create the context with the job and include the context with the job, rather than including a timestamp with the job and creating the context elsewhere.

Comment: @Adrian If the point is to assign context to job - I'm agree, it's also valid option and more precise in terms of timeout since job created. Updated my answer, added it as another option.